# Sendkeys is inconsistent in selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am using sendkeys to upload a file, but for some reason it is very inconsistent. I have two scenarios that would upload a file (attach a file on main Window then attach a file on the second window). If I use my first scenario which is attaching a file on main window without attaching a file on second window, this works perfectly. I also did the same on the second window and it works fine, but when I run both, the sendkeys won't key in my exact string. here is the code:

AttachFileTA.cs:

```
  IWebElement fileAttachTA = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//object[@class='ruObject']"));
fileAttachTA.Click();

         //Switch into the windows upload dialog

         Thread.Sleep(1000);
         SendKeys.SendWait(file);
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
         SendKeys.SendWait(@"{Enter}");
         Thread.Sleep(1000);
         SendKeys.Flush();
```

Main.cs:

```
 createDraftTA.FillGeneralInfo("This is a fourth positive test created from Selenium Webdriver");
 addPrepaid.AddPrePaid("test", "Comment");
```

AddPrepaid.cs:

```
  commentsBox.SendKeys("COMMENT");        
  CreateTANonProxy_Domestic attachFile = new CreateTANonProxy_Domestic(driver);
  attachFile.AttachFileTA("\\Users\\My Documents\\file.txt");
```

FillGeneralInfo.cs

```
purposeBox.SendKeys(purpose);
AttachFileTA("\\Users\\My Documents\\file.txt");
```

What is the best way to upload a file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, looks like you have misunderstood the `SendKeys` here. Please note that in your code `SendKeys` is C# class and not a Selenium Method.

[More about `SendKeys' class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys(v=vs.110).aspx)

`SendKeys` (C#) class is not reliable for handing windows based popup when you use it in Selenium. Instead of it, try using other alternatives for file uploading for ex. [AutoIt tool](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit-tools/). 
on the top of this, try to find out the way AutoIt works and implement the solution to handle the file uploading in Selenium WebDriver.